# Need better performance: best alternative for Lion's built in VNC server?

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm connecting to my work's iMac through VNC. On the client side I use JollysFastVNC (on my Mac at home) and as server I use Lion's built in VNC server.
The appearance is just great but the overall performance sucks.
I would prefer less quality and gain a bit of performance instead.
Unfortunately Lion's VNC server only allows high-quality connections. Only thing I can adjust is the color depth.

Is there a better free VNC server for Lion?

Answer (score 2):

## [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/)

It doesn't use VNC, but it works very well. You can adjust the settings for better speed, quality, etc:

[image]

And you don't have to set up any port forwarding on your firewall, it all goes through the TeamViewer servers. I highly recommend it.

Comment: I use this to support clients spread all over the world. It works great. Would recommend it for better speed.

Comment: Not an option. I need VNC :-(